# How can I run blender from command line or a python script without opening a GUI?

Tags: python, command-line

I'm interested in using Blender for producing images, 3d files, or calculating geometry on a server.

Can I make blender run a python script without opening a GUI?

If not, can I incorporate Blender's python API into my own python script without running a GUI?

Comment: also read through other questions tagged with command-line: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line

Comment: @zeffii thanks. I was aware that Blender could render from command line, but was unsure of broader usage. At this point all the command line questions deal with rendering.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

## Command-line / subprocess

- You can use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html) to run blender (like any other application) from python.
- Use the `-b` / `--background` switch to run blender in the backgroud (GUI-less).
- Use the `-P <filename>` / `--python <filename>` switch to load desired python script.

  - Or use `--python-console` to run python from stdin.

Example: `blender --background --python myscript.py`

See: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html

## As module

This is an experimental feature and not enabled by default, but Blender can be [compiled as a python module](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule).

> This allows 'bpy' to be imported from python or other applications/IDE's which embed python

Comment: The "compiled as a python module" link is broken

Comment: I think [these](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule) are the updated instructions for Blender 2.8.

Answer (score 35):

All what **Aldrik** wrote, and more [Blender Python API Tips and Tricks](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_tips_and_tricks.html)

From official Blender documentation:

For scripts that are not interactive it can end up being more efficient not to use Blenders interface at all and instead execute the script on the command line.

```
blender --background --python myscript.py
```

You might want to run this with a blend file so the script has some data to operate on.

```
blender myscene.blend --background --python myscript.py
```

Comment: Links can go down. Please write some parts of the link.

Comment: This is the link to the official Blender API documentation, even if the link will be broken, then anyone can find documentation. Anyway, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 8):

For 2.79b

```
#blender --background --factory-startup --python $HOME/background_job.py -- \
#          --text="Hello World" \
#          --render="/tmp/hello" \
#          --save="/tmp/hello.blend"
#
# Notice:
# '--factory-startup' is used to avoid the user default settings from
#                     interfering with automated scene generation.
#
# '--' causes blender to ignore all following arguments so python can use them.
#
# See blender --help for details.
```

Answer (score 5):

you can also directly run expressions without having to create a new .py file
like this:

```
blender "/path/to/file.blend" -b --python-expr "import bpy;print(bpy.data.filepath)"
```

In case anyone wants to run a script which involves indentations, for e.g. a loop:

```
blender "/path/to/file.blend" -b --python-expr $'import bpy\nfor obj in bpy.data.objects:\n    print(obj.name)'
```

You can also run one script from a blender file to change another blend file!

```
import bpy,subprocess

file_path="/path/to/another/file.blend"

code='''
import bpy
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        print(obj.name)
'''

output = subprocess.check_output(f"blender '{file_path}' -b --python-expr '{code}'", shell=True)
print(output.decode('UTF-8'))
```

Heck, if you're crazy enough you can run a script from one blend file to run a script in *another* blend file all in a one liner from the command line

```
blender "/path/to/file.blend" -b --python-expr $'import bpy,subprocess\nprint("Objects in file ",bpy.data.filepath)\nfor obj in bpy.data.objects:\n        print(obj.name)\nfile_path="/path/to/another/file.blend"\ncode="""\nimport bpy\nprint("Objects in file ",bpy.data.filepath)\nfor obj in bpy.data.objects:\n        print(obj.name)\n"""\noutput = subprocess.check_output(f"blender \'{file_path}\' -b --python-expr \'{code}\'", shell=True)\nprint(output.decode(\'UTF-8\'))\n'
```

The possibilities are endless

Comment: is it possible to run loops with python expressions?

Comment: @JuanManuelLynch yes it is! I've updated the answer