# Can I run a Python script step by step in Blender?

Tags: scripting, python

Can I run a python script step by step with normal blender, a build, external software or an addon?

I'm developing a script (town generator) and I want to  to execute the code step by step like a debugger. Is this possible?

Edit: it's possible with the eclipse software check this [link](http://daniepstein.com/daniepstein/tutorials/python-blender-and-a-bit-of-debuggery)

Comment: Can you explain the purpose? do you mean interactively step over the code as with a debugger?, or just that you execute code one line at a time (so a python script could be streamed from an external source, or to listen for commands and execute one line at a time, for eg). What kind of interaction with Blender are you wanting to do between each line execution?

Comment: I want to execute the code step by step like a debugger. I would that blender execute the code a bit like if i enter my pyhton script line by line in the python console and like that i can see what append.

Comment: Please edit your question to make this more clear.

Comment: You could also use the Blender [BreakPoint Addon](http://goodspiritgraphics.com/software/products/breakpoint-addon/), it stops at breakpoints and dumps local or global variables. The hosting site also provides video tutorials.

Comment: You can use [this](https://code.blender.org/2015/10/debugging-python-code-with-pycharm/) amazing addon. It'll allow you to debug blender with PyCharm.

Comment: In 2020, the easiest way to do this is with this extension for Visual Studio Code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JacquesLucke.blender-development

Comment: I have upvoted Justin, but would like to stress it: DO choose this option.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

1. Launch blender from a terminal emulator.
2. Add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to your code where you wish to start debugging from.
3. Run your code and you'll be put into [the Python debugger](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pdb.html), where you can use <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to step through the code.

See the [pdb documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands) for more info on usage. Also for the nicer [ipython](http://ipython.org/) debugger (features syntax highlighting and tab completion), you can use [ipdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb).

Answer (score 16):

**No**, Blender can't do this with the default feature set.

*Edit: As Aldrik says, you can use `pdb`, however blender can't step over python code in its own interface.*

There are however some things you *can* do that may be of interest to you.

## Load as a python module

If you compile Blender as a Python module, you can use any Python IDE which supports debugging/stepping, The times I really wanted to step over Python code I did this, however it can't be used with a Blender window active.

See:
[How can I run blender from command line or a python script without opening a GUI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/how-can-i-run-blender-from-command-line-or-a-python-script-without-opening-a-gui)

## Use the command line REPL

REPL, being (Read–eval–print loop).
Python has a module that you can use to create a python interactive console, it can be used to execute scripts one line at a time.

See: http://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html

The example below executes 3 lines of python script, then prints a variable which the script defined:

```
import code
namespace = {}
console = code.InteractiveConsole(
    locals=namespace,
    filename="<blender_console>",
)

# Code - can be anything... 
# load an entire text file into this for eg.
my_code = [
    "a = 1",
    "b = 2",
    "c = a + b",
]

# execute the script line by line.
for line in my_code:
    console.push(line)

# get something back from the executed code
print(namespace["c"])
```