# Is there a way to restart a modified addon?

Tags: scripting, python, add-on

I'm currently twiddling with an old addon and insert some print statements for debugging. Currently I'm restarting Blender each time to see the new messages. Is there a way to 'refresh' an already loaded Python script?

An API call would be preferred to disable/re-enable the addon in the *User Preferences* dialog.

Comment: If `print` is getting tiresome, you might be interest in [this question about debugging](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2502/290).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can go to the *Main menu > Blender > System > Reload Scripts*. As the name suggests, the operator reloads all addons and scripts, running addons, `unregister` and `register` functions.

[image]

Another way is hitting <kbd>F3</kbd> and typing "Reload Scripts" in the *Operator Search* menu and execute the operator. In versions pre Blender 2.8x you can just hit <kbd>F8</kbd> in order to reload.

Comment: Thanks this works, unfourtunatly it doesn't care about my opened sockets and complains that I tried to open the socket twice (OSError: [WinError 10048]).  Is there a 'harder' reload. This should probably another question. I will upvote later (run out of upvotes for today).

Comment: @stacker, you could handle any resources (sockets, open files etc), in the addons `unregister` function. This should allow you to support cleaning up before reloading

Comment: It is worth noting that this will only reload the `__init__.py` portion of the addon.  Any changes in imported sub-modules will not be registered unless Blender is re-opened or code is included in accordance with this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28505/3292

Comment: In Blender 2.8 `F8` doesn't work out of the box anymore. Search with `F3` for `reload scripts` or remap it yourself (answer from: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/reload-button-in-2-8/1708)

Comment: The place to add the shortcut, as seen in the image in the above link, can be found: `Preferences -> Keymap -> Screen -> Screen (Global) -> Add New -> collapse`, then enter `script.reload` with your desired shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

To reload a Blender Addon at the console type:

```py
>>> bpy.ops.wm.addon_enable(module='your_module_name')
```

Note: under-the-hood Blender uses Python's [`imp.reload`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) to reload modules.

One of its caveats is that the module dictionary will *not* be replaced.  Since that is where module globals are stored, this can lead to surprises (if expecting a pristine module state after reload).

As such, restarting Blender semi-frequently is still a good idea even when using console reloading during development.

Note that the `imp.reload` behavior can also be used (with care) as a debug-enabling tool; for example, to "persist" a network socket across Addon reloads:

```
try:
    socket_that_survives_reloads
except NameError:
    socket_that_survives_reloads = None

if not socket_that_survives_reloads:
    print("creating new socket connection")
    socket_that_survives_reloads = however_you_connect()
else:
    print("re-using existing socket connection")
```

Comment: I have compiled Blender as a Python3 module so I don't have access to the GUI. I am installing an addon and enable it using the function you pointed. I then save the user preferences using `bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()` and exit Python.Next time that I do `import bpy` I don't see the addon API being added to the bpy module.Do you know how I can fix that?If I run the same exact script in Blender terminal (when using the GUI) everything works.(You may answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118584/why-the-addon-installation-succeeds-but-the-api-is-not-accessible-through-the-bp))

Comment: In Blender 2.80 the correct code shortcut to reload ALL add-ons is: `bpy.ops.script.reload()` (https://developer.blender.org/T66924). `bpy.ops.wm.addon_enable(module='your_module_name')` won't work for multi-file add-ons, as there is a check, which only looks at whether `__init__.py` has changed.

Answer (score 2):

To enable and disable via the API use [`bpy.ops.wm.addon_enable`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68a_release/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.addon_enable), and [`bpy.ops.wm.addon_disable`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68a_release/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.addon_disable) respectively.

Comment: Not the recommended way for Blender 2.8 according to a Blender developer Sybren: https://developer.blender.org/T66924 . Instead use `bpy.ops.script.reload()`