# Is there a way to modify python scripts without constantly restarting Blender?

Tags: python

I am currently modifying an existing addons. My workflow is to change something in the python code then restart Blender to see the effect.

Is there a way to update the script without restarting Blender to check result? That would make my development process faster.

Thanks!

Comment: Try opening said script in the builtin text editor and pressing the *Run Script* button with the *Register* box ticked

Comment: F8 reloads all addons.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28505/3292 if your addon has multiple files.