# How to reload an Addon to see changes?

Tags: python, add-on

I'm developing an addon, and originally I made it as a single file.

When it was like that, I could simply execute "Reload scripts" in Blender to reload the changes I did to the script.

But after separating it into a package, I noticed the "reload scripts" dont work anymore, it doesn't show new changes. I need to close Blender and load the file again to see the changes. Is not that the script has a problem or anything. After re-executing blender again, the changes I made (like simple prints()) show.

But is a bit... clumsy, having to quit and reload over and over.

Do you know how can I reload my addon without quiting blender?

(I also tried disabling and enabling it from addons, but dont work)

Comment: Hello. I can't recommend enough this how to for developping using an external IDE https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/using-microsoft-visual-studio-code-as-external-ide-for-writing-blender-scripts-add-ons/ It automatically updates your addon when you save the text file (you do have to enable it in the plugin settings)

Comment: Ty so much, you are always helping friend. I followed it (specially the part about multifile addons (https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/debugging-multifile-blender-add-on-by-quick-reinstall/)), but sadly I wasn't able to make it work after battling for hours. Not sure if the article is outdated (it says is for 2.79). I tried changing missing parts (bpy.ops.wm.addon_install and enable dont exist in current Blender version).

I think the problem is that I have sub folders (with classes, icons) and such. Only root files are "reinstalled"/copied, but not sub folders, they are missing. Any idea?

Comment: If you have subfolders, you should add a file called `__init__.py` in every folder. The file contents can be empty (no text), but the file should be there. Last I checked it was still usable for newer version, autocomplete is not mandatory for it to work, but it's helpful. IIRC there are recent versions on the autocomplete github

Comment: Yes, I have __init__.py in the folders (if now they would not be recognized and the addon wont work). But their content is copied from temp to the root, is ignoring original subdirectories.

What you mean with autocomplete?

And you mean this repo https://github.com/JacquesLucke/code_autocomplete ? (it says it was updated 8 years ago). I wasnt able to find reload examples.

Comment: I'm using VS Code for an IDE. This is the easiest way I've found to install the autocomplete: you can get the most up to date autocomplete files at: https://github.com/nutti/fake-bpy-module On the right hand side of that page where it says Releases, click the Latest button. You can get a zip file for the Blender version you want. You don't have to use pip, or any of the other methods to install it. The "Korchy" Github files link from the ".b3d, etc." page @Gorgious mentioned come from the "nutti" page. Continued...

Comment: The files on the "nutti" page I refer to can be used by creating a folder, unzip the file in that folder and follow the instructions regarding setting up the settings JSON file on the "b3d" page Gorgious mentioned. It has been a long time, so I might be wrong, but I seem to remember that if the multi file addon you are working on is what you have installed in Blender, that what Gorgious says in the first comment works.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @curious_1! I have to say that Im kinda lost; does the autocomplete help with reloading the addon? I mean, I was already using vscode (vscodium to be precise) and the autocomplete already works perfectly for me.

My problem is that after changing the addon into multiple files, the reload scripts operator inside blender doesn't update changes anymore (I read somwhere that it only reloads the __init__.py, so changes in other files are ignored)

Comment: My bad guys! I was using VSCodium instead of VSCode. Despite I thought I had everything setted correctly (and also having the Auto Reload on save that @Gorgious said, seems the extension wasn't working propperly). I installed VSCode and omg, works great. Im surprised the debug is working. But I still not sure what I have to do for my addon to be recognized for auto reload. I have this message: https://i.imgur.com/Ek873rC.png (I guess those two are being reloaded, but mine not). Any chance you know some manual or tutorial for this?

Comment: "does the autocomplete help with reloading the addon?" No. And, after a quick test with the multi file addon I was thinking of, which has all the files in one folder, nothing new appeared after making some changes and reloading it. I must have been remembering a single file addon when I said I thought that reload worked. Unfortunately, I don't know of any tutorial, etc., that mentions reload for a multi file addon, or one using multiple folders.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @curious_1 :) I finally managed to solve it (I edited the post, if you want to know how). Yeah, with single files works great. In case you dont have installed, I recommend you a lot the Blender Development extension for VSCode. Even though the documentation is very poor IMHO (it says that it handles automatically auto-loading existing addons, but it don't specify how).
Thanks again for the help guys, much appreciated :)

Comment: For auto-reloading go to the preferences in VScode, in the Extensions panel look for Blender, then look for Reload on Save https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqFXJ.png BTW on this site you should write your answer in a new post in the bottom of this page (Named "Your Answer") instead of updating the question, otherwise it won't be recognized as a solved topic. You can also check the green mark afterwards so it can be archived as solved and get referenced for future use. Cheers

Comment: sorry, my bad @Gorgious. And yes, I had that option on. I think I've done everything the addon says (basically start blender with the vscode command, doesn't say much more). And when saving it sends a message: https://i.imgur.com/Ek873rC.png (Im not sure if those are the only addons that were reloaded. TESTAUTOLOAD was an addon test I made with the extension commands in vscode. I saw it has an ´auto_reload.py´. I tried copying to mine and adjusting my `__init__.py` to look as the one from the script generated. But no luck. I dont know how to make it work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution I've found**

It is a Python thing. Once a module is imported, the interpreter won't automatically reload the changes.

So, when we reload the scripts in Blender (using operator "Reload Scripts"), Blender is only "truly reloading" the **init**.py files of the addons. But not the rest of the modules. We have to handle by ourselves.

Here is how ([original source](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28504/blender-ignores-changes-to-python-scripts)):

```
# (In your __init__.py)
# When bpy is already in local, we know this is not the initial import...
if "bpy" in locals():
    # ...so we need to reload our submodule(s) using importlib
    import importlib
    if "my_submodule" in locals():
        importlib.reload(my_submodule)


# This is only relevant on first run, on later reloads those modules
# are already in locals() and those statements do not do anything.
import bpy
import my_submodule
```

This way, the "Reload Scripts" will work as normal with multiple-files addons.