# Script wise functionality of F8 to reload Addon

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I want to reload an addon using a script, however I cannot get the same functionality as pressing F8.

### What I'm trying to do:

The addon `manuelbastionilab` (http://www.manuelbastioni.com/) has some .json files which specify how to change blendshapes to make certain expressions. If I modify such a .json, it is not detected in Blender. If I press `F8`, this addon with its .json files are reloaded and everything is good.

However, now I want to achieve the same functionality in a script.

### What I tried

As suggest here: [Is there a way to restart a modified addon?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/is-there-a-way-to-restart-a-modified-addon) , I tried different combinations of (open Python console with `Shift+F4`):

```
bpy.utils.unregister_module('manuelbastionilab')
bpy.utils.register_module('manuelbastionilab')
bpy.ops.wm.addon_disable(module='manuelbastionilab')
bpy.ops.wm.addon_disable(module='manuelbastionilab')
```

But all didn't give the same functionality as F8. If I use one of these code lines in the build-in terminal in Blender, it does reload the addon, but the .json files are not reloaded.

I also tried `import bge` and then `bge.events.F8KEY`, but I get a `NameError: name 'bge' is not defined`.

### Question

How do I get script-wise the exact same functionality as `F8`? But preferably only for 1 addon?

Comment: F8 is the equivalent of `bpy.ops.script.reload()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me in the Python console in Blender (`Shift+F4` to open):

```
import imp
import manuelbastionilab  # addon name
imp.reload(manuelbastionilab)
bpy.ops.wm.addon_enable(module='manuelbastionilab')
```

Comment: Single line command for Blender 2.8 to reload 1 add-on: `bpy.ops.preferences.addon_enable(module='manuelbastionilab')`