# Can Blender process an image on a webserver?

Tags: rendering

Does any one know how to achieve the following...

I'd like people to be able to submit a .jpg image via a web page. Once the image has been submitted I'd like blender to texture an object using the submitted .jpg image. And then I'd like the final render to be emailed back the the person who submitted the .jpg image.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/how-can-i-run-blender-from-command-line-or-a-python-script-without-opening-a-gui

Comment: Can you be more specific about what part of the process (within blender) you are interested in? As it stands, the linked question is most likely a dupe, but if the command line part is not what you are having trouble with, then could you please elaborate?

Comment: Hi. I'm wondering if Blender can be used on a webserver to enable people to submit an image, which is then used to texture an object. The resultant image is then emailed back the submitter.

Comment: Hello, I'm hoping for some progress on my question. Does anyone know if it's possible?

Comment: So essentially you want to use Blender as web service with it running elsewhere while all data to input is fed via remote computer (not only rendering). There isn't any built-in way to do it afaik and while there were some addons being created a while ago they weren't finished from what it seems. While you can write your own  addon for that like in [controling Blender via browser](https://www.blendernation.com/2019/04/05/controlling-blender-from-the-browser/) it requires quite a bit of coding and Blender knowledge