# Is there a way to access blender file's material from command line?

Tags: rendering, materials, command-line

I was wondering if there is anyway that i can increase or decrease strength of emission material via command line.. Scenario is I am using google colab for rendering which do not have GUI. So, process is first install blender in VM via command line then link the google drive and run the command wich will read file from google drive and will render in blender installed in VM. So, for just to change emission strength from 2 to 5 I have to upload 300 mb file to gdrive and It is costing too much data. SO, If there is any way that I can access the material strength and  resolution, from command line will be a good option to change some values rather than uploading whole file.

Comment: Sure, via python expression or by specifying a python file: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/how-can-i-run-blender-from-command-line-or-a-python-script-without-opening-a-gui

Comment: @brockmann Hey, thanks for suggestion. Unfortunately I am not able to understand whether this is solving my problem or not. It is written that It is switching blender to background and then running a script. Actually, I want to edit the blender file and modify it's content. There is no option to edit the python file and then run it with blender file. So, I am partially confused. Would you please help me with my confusion?

Comment: Not sure where your confusion comes from... In other words: you can specify a script file like `my_edits.py` to edit your blend when launching blender via command line: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html