# Error During Running Python file in a Blender Subprocess from blender

Tags: python, command-line

I am working on this code from the post: [How can I run blender from command line or a python script without opening a GUI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/how-can-i-run-blender-from-command-line-or-a-python-script-without-opening-a-gui)

I am trying to open a blend file and have a script run in that blend file to do some actions.

but I get error while running this code from the above post

```
import bpy
import subprocess

f_path = 'C:/Users/naman/Desktop/test.blend'


code = """
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    print(obj.name)

"""
 
output = subprocess.check_output( f"blender '{f_path}' -b --python-expr '{code}' ", shell = 
True)
print(output.decode('UTF-8'))
```

Error in the Blender
[image]

Comment: This looks like a near-duplicate of the later https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/293440/how-to-run-script-in-a-new-blender-subprocess . I'll close this one, assumng the later one is more correct. If you need to expand / make adjustments, please do so, in your other post.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a near duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/293440/how-to-run-script-in-a-new-blender-subprocess

Comment: No, It's not entirely similar, on the link u mentioned I am asking how to open a blender subprocess and work code on it, In this post I am trying to open an existing file as subprocess, Check F_path for both the post

Comment: Hi, @NamanDeep, Thanks for the correction This was actually flagged for the duplicate _answer_, given to both posts. I don't know if it helps, I deleted the copy on this post. I'll reopen your question. Sorry for any inconvenience.