# How to run script in a new blender subprocess

Tags: python, command-line

In my code I am trying to open a new blender subprocess with this code

I am trying to do some action like this
how to run a give **code = ''' import bpy'''** like in code below, in that new blender subprocess
how to run like a script in that new sub process that opens
Example Script : 'C:/Users/Desktop/my_script.py'

```
import bpy
import subprocess

blenpath = 'C:/Program Files/Blender Foundation/Blender 2.93/blender.exe'

code = '''
import bpy
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj.name = 'test_name'
'''

# how to run the code above in that new blender subprocess
# how to run like a script in that new sub process that opens 
# Example Script : 'C:/Users/Desktop/my_script.py'

cmd = [blenpath]
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See all the python options here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#python-options

```
import bpy
import subprocess

temp_blend_path = 'C:/Users/naman/Desktop/test.blend'

filepath = 'C:/Users/Desktop/my_script.py'

process = subprocess.Popen([bpy.app.binary_path, "--factory-startup", "-b", temp_blend_path, "--python", filepath], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
process.wait()
```

Comment: Can I know how, to open a subprocess, instead of an existing file? like another instance of blender and run the code in it.

Comment: Also u wrote a code in the expression, What if I want to get a code from a script I written in a directory,  'C:/Users/Desktop/my_script.py' , like this

Comment: learn more https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#python-options

Comment: argument order https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#argument-order

Comment: I understand these shows arguments for command line, can u do it so I can easily implement into the subprocess.Popen instead, how to run a script in the opened subprocess,

Comment: remove the `"--python-expr", expression` and use `"--python", <filepath>`