# Interact with Blender from external program

Tags: python

Is it possible to run blender from another python program? I need to start blender and execute multiple bpy commands. However, I cannot even figure a way to check whether the startup process of blender is already complete. Is there a way to do this? Also when Blender is open, amongst others I need to import a DXF file using the AutoCAD DXF add-on. But I do not want to call a dialog to select the file, instead I want to pass the filepath automatically to the code of the add-on and then let it do the import. But I can't figure out how. Anyone got experience with that? Also excuse me, if this is a super obvious question, I am a beginner with this.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/how-can-i-run-blender-from-command-line-or-a-python-script-without-opening-a-gui